# Making Imageview disappear After Animation

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, visibility

I have a method that creates an animation for an ImageView object with specified parameters:

```
public void animateMove(float x, float y, int milsecs)
{
    float origX = view.getX();
    float origY = view.getY();

    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Path linePath = new Path();
    linePath.lineTo(x, y);

    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", "translationY", linePath);
    anim.setDuration(milsecs);
    anim.start();

    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // this code is the problem
    view.setX(origX);
    view.setY(origY);

}
```

However, when I call the setVisibility method to make the ImageView invisible, it runs at the same time as when the animation is occurring and so nothing can actually be seen. If I remove this piece of code, I can see the animation of the view just fine.

How can I have this method create an animation and turns it invisible only AFTER the whole animation is complete?

Comment: did you check `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator` / `Animator` javadocs?

Comment: I did but I was not able to find any information pertaining to something like this problem. If you have, could you quote a part where it does explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: so read `Animator` docs again, carefully

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html#start() - I've read this twice now. Maybe I'm not a good reader but where does it state that if start() is called, code below it can also run at the same time? I apologize if there is information that I'm not seeing in the docs but if you haven't read the docs yourself first, please don't ask me to when the information is not there.

Comment: so did you check what AnimatorListener is used for?

Comment: I never thought about using AnimatorListener in the 1st place. I thought that my code should have worked perfectly fine without it. I'm very new to android development but next time I'll make sure to try more varied approaches to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code before `anim.start()`:

```
anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    view.setX(origX);
                    view.setY(origY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Mind if I ask, did you just know that beforehand or did you read some doc/tutorial. If so, could you send the link?

Comment: I remember using AnimatorListener before. I'm sure there are many examples here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of `ObjectAnimator`'s state info methods such as `isRunning()` or `isStarted()`

```
if(anim.isStarted()) {
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
```